# Grab input from text file and use in CLI vbs/batch

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to change a QueueDepth setting on several HBAs witin our environment.  I am horrible with scripting, but I am trying to stumble through it so that we don't need to implement this change manually.

The short version goes this, I got some other scripts (currently working) that gathers a bunch of port information about the HBA and puts it into a text file.  Another script searches through the files to dissect the WWN/WWID information and puts that into another text file.

Those WWNs from the text file need to be inserted into a CLI command.  To illustrate further:

Sample text file that I need info pulled from:

```
10:44:24:44:a1:b1:c1:d1
10:41:42:44:a1:b2:c1:d2
10:24:14:22:a1:b1:c1:d1
```

Command that requires that info `(**<WWN>**)`:

```
hbacmd SetDriverParam **<WWN>** G P QueueDepth 32
```

Comment: My sample text file didn't display as I expected.  Those WWNs are actually listed on separate lines throughout the file.  Typically, there will only be (2), but sometime as much as (8).

Answer (score 0):

If the WWN lines don't contain additional text you could extract them like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^[0-9a-e]{2}(:[0-9a-e]{2}){7}$"
re.IgnoreCase = True

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\your\input.txt")
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  line = f.ReadLine
  If re.Test(line) Then
    sh.Run "hbacmd SetDriverParam " & line & " G P QueueDepth 32", 0, True
  End If
Loop
f.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is enough for you?

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%a in (inputFile.txt) do (
    ECHO hbacmd SetDriverParam %%a G P QueueDepth 32
)
```

If not, please post additional details, so I can fix the problem.

Above program just *display* the final `hbacmd` commands. If they are correct, delete the `ECHO` part, so the commands be really executed.